# General solution of $\sin(x) = -1/2$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a doubt with regards to the general solution of **$\sin(\theta) = -1/2$**.

I know that the principal solutions are $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ and  $\frac{11\pi}{6}$.

So my main question is: Should the general solution be $n\pi$ + $(-1)^{n}$$\frac{7\pi}{6}$ or $n\pi$ + $(-1)^{n}$$\frac{11\pi}{6}$?

Apparently, WolframAlpha uses $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ for the general solution. My apologies to you if you found this question a bit silly. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Both of your expressions are valid, and generate the same set of solutions. So it seems reasonable to use $7\pi/6$ instead of $11\pi/6$, simply because it's smaller. (Another possibility is $n\pi-(-1)^n\pi/6$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, since$$3\pi+(-1)^3\frac{7\pi}6=\frac{11\pi}6\quad\text{and}\quad3\pi+(-1)^3\frac{11\pi}6=\frac{7\pi}6.$$So, you get the same solutions in both cases.

Comment: Thanks. Also, another formula for the general solution of $\sin(\theta)$ is $(2n+1)\pi - \theta$ and $2n\pi + \theta$. However, the formula that we talked about is $n\pi + (-1)^{1}\theta$. If I understood it correctly, they let $n = 2n+1$ or $n = 2n$; where n are just random integer, right?

Comment: @Gtexx: Yes, they just describe it differently for even and odd $n$, whereas $(-1)^n$ summarises both in the same case.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See if this helps:

We know $\sin{\theta}$ is negative in quadrants 3 & 4:

Therefore, for Quadrants 3 & 4, these formulas can be used respectively:
$$\text{Quadrant 3: } (2n + 1)\pi + \theta$$
$$\text{Quadrant 4: } 2\pi(n + 1) - \theta$$
where $n$ denotes, the rotation (repeat; as the cycle repeats ever $2\pi$) count and $\theta$ is, well, your angle (which, the base is, $\frac{\pi}{6}$)